# URL component % and \x

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I have a doubt.

```
st = "b%C3%BCrokommunikation"
urllib2.unquote(st)
```

OUTPUT: 'b\xc3\xbcrokommunikation'
But, if I print it:

```
print urllib2.unquote(st)
```

OUTPUT: bürokommunikation

Why is the difference?
I have to write bürokommunikation instead of 'b\xc3\xbcrokommunikation' into a file.

My problem is:
I have lots of data with such values extracted from URLs. I have to store them as eg. bürokommunikation into a text file.

Comment: You say that you have to write "bürokommunikation" into a file. Do you know what encoding you should be using? A file contains bytes, not letters, so you'll need to decide how the letter `ü` should be represented as a sequence of bytes in the file. (I'm assuming that you'll be using some ASCII-based encoding, so the non-accented letters are represented using their ASCII equivalents.)

Comment: Yup, will be using ASCII

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense: the ASCII encoding doesn't include the character `ü`, so you *can't* use ASCII. Why is why I asked what encoding you'll be using. :-)

Comment: I have no idea. I have lots of data with such values extracted from URLs. I have to store them as eg. bürokommunikation into a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `print` the string, your terminal emulator recognizes the unicode character `\xc3\xbc` and displays it correctly.

However, as @MarkDickinson says in the comments, `ü` doesn't exist in ASCII, so you'll need to tell Python that the string you want to write to a file is unicode encoded, and what encoding format you want to use, for instance [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

This is very easy using the `codecs` library:

```
import codecs

# First create a Python UTF-8 string
st = "b%C3%BCrokommunikation"
encoded_string = urllib2.unquote(st).decode('utf-8')

# Write it to file keeping the encoding
with codecs.open('my_file.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(encoded_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the same result. when you try to print it without print command, it just show the `__repr__()` result. when you use print, it shows the unicode character instead of escaping it with \x