# Which string encoding is this?

Tags: javascript, string, encoding

On one of my webhooks, I am receiving the following string

```
9\x09?\x09\x02\x09&\x09@
```

This was supposed to be the text in regional language. For English, the content seems fine. But for vernacular strings, the service provider is sending this. Consider that I am using Javascript, how do I decode this string?

This is how the webhook is being called :

`/api/test?content=9\x09?\x09\x02\x09&\x09@&timestamp=20210120145223`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL component % and \x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379432/url-component-and-x)

Comment: Partially, I want to know if the service provider is sending the correct data or not. If the above string is in ASCII, and the characters were supposed to be in unicode, what should I do? Is it like the service provider has messed up with the content, or I can retrieve the actual text from those ASCII characters

Comment: Doesn't look right to me `\x09` is a tab character.

Comment: Yes, seems incorrect. Let me speak to the service provider. Thanks. This was supposed to be vernacular language content

Comment: Are you receiving actual escape sequences with backslashes, or is that just how the non-printable U+0009 character is displayed in your log? Of course, percent-encoding would be more suitable

Comment: When I check logs, I see GET request in the following way
`/api/test?content=9\x09?\x09\x02\x09&\x09@&timestamp=20210120145223`

Comment: I am printing Nginx access logs in the terminal using cat command

Comment: In Python, `'9\x09?\x09\x02\x09&\x09'.encode('ascii').decode('utf-16le')` returns `'हिंद'` (a Devanagari string)…

Answer (score -1):

It's ASCII. All occurrences of the four characters \xST are converted to 1 character, whose ASCII code is ST (in hexadecimal), where S and T are any of 0123456789abcdefABCDEF.

Comment: How do I convert this to human-readable format?

Comment: To me, it doesn't seem ASCII. It may be read as ASCII, but it would be a very strange string.